# Switch between site languages on the same page (using jQuery )

Tags: jquery

how i can switch between site language without change current page . 
for example :

> mydomain.com/**en**/support/default.aspx

when i click on Arabic link i want to change link to:

> mydomain.com/**ar**/support/default.aspx

with the knowledge that i have a site in Arabic and in English the same site links.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery

Comment: Do you mean without **reloading** the current page or without having to go through the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
First assign an id attribute to the link.
using JQuery

```
$('#linkId').attr('href', $('#link').attr('href').replace('ar','en')) //or 'en','ar'
```

or to automatically toggle between ar and en:

```
link = $('#linkId');
if (link.attr('href').match('en') != null)
   link.attr('href',link.attr('href').replace('en','ar'));
else
   link.attr('href',link.attr('href').replace('ar','en'));
```

Comment: I mean redirect link. change the characters (en to ar) in the current link .

Comment: Edited, check out the code and tell me if that's what you need